# No such column SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Okay i tried everyting i could, i saw all the posts here about this error and none of them solved my problem:

Here is my simple update statement, i would like to increment each itemSlotIndex by 1 at a certain characterName

```
String myQuery = "UPDATE " + theTable.getTableName() + " SET " + theTable.getItemSlotIndex()

        + " = " + theTable.getItemSlotIndex() + " + 1 WHERE " + theTable.getCharName() + " = "+character.getName();

        Log.i("myQuery", myQuery);

        theDatabase.execSQL(myQuery);
```

If this mumbo jumbo could be misleading, here is my logcat output for the SQL statement:

```
UPDATE CharsTable SET slot_index = slot_index + 1 WHERE char_name = Francis
```

As you see,

CharsTable is my table

slot_index is the attribute, i would like to increment

and the where claus is: I only want to update rows with char_name equals "Francis"

And the error is just wow:

```
02-06 19:01:13.472: E/SQLiteLog(16743): (1) no such column: Francis
```

No such column!!!

I got no such column error for adding a where clause parameter.

Any ideas what m i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgot the '' around Francis :

```
UPDATE CharsTable SET slot_index = slot_index + 1 WHERE char_name = 'Francis'

... + " = '"+character.getName() + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes around your string value?

Comment: It is exactly the same answer as Rida posted above, I was simply not as verbose.  Just because there is a question mark does not mean I am asking a question.