# no such column: hey (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT ID FROM ALLWORKHOURS WHERE NOTEMEMOS = hey

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqlite-net

Log Cat:

```
no such column: hey (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT ID FROM ALLWORKHOURS WHERE NOTEMEMOS = hey
```

code:

```
    102) public String getID(String note){
    103)      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    104)      String  query = ("SELECT " + COL_0 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_5 + " = " + note);
    105)      db.rawQuery(query,null);
    106)      return query;
    107) }
```

I do have a column name hey in my Database
[Database Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8M34.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such column SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610600/no-such-column-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terminology is confused.

hey is a value, NOTEMEMOS is a column.

You need to quote the value hey to let the SQL compiler know that it is a string value, rather than a column you are trying to compare against.

```java
String  query = ("SELECT " + COL_0 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_5 + " = '" + note + "'");
```

Just a note, you would be better off using a parameterised query, as using raw values is insecure (see SQL injection).

```java
String  query = ("SELECT " + COL_0 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_5 + " = ?"); // That's right, quotes aren't needed for a parameterized query.
String result = "";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,new String[] {note} );
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_0));
}
cursor.close();
return result;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful!

Comment: I also just learned something new. I did not know about "parameterised query's" thank you sir! I am a beginner!

Comment: Thou art welcome and thou should be commended for bothering to mark as answer!

Comment: As thy wish my lord!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this

```
SELECT ID FROM ALLWORKHOURS WHERE NOTEMEMOS = 'hey'
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: no, it did not work. Also, it cannot be hard coded.

Comment: It have to be in the format that the function "getID" is in

Answer (score 0):

The way that you concatenate the parameter `note` creates this sql statement:

```
SELECT ID FROM ALLWORKHOURS WHERE NOTEMEMOS = hey
```

so `hey` is considered a column identifier and not a string literal because it is not enclosed inside single quotes.
You could do this instead:

```
String  query = "SELECT " + COL_0 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_5 + " = '" + note + "'";
```

and it would work.
 
But the recommended way is passing parameters as a string array like this:

```
String  query = "SELECT " + COL_0 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_5 + " = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {note});
return cursor;
```

This way you don't worry about single quotes as this is taken care of by `rawQuery()`.
I guess you want to return the `Cursor` object and not the sql query string, right?

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful!

Comment: @DarkShadow is there any reason that you accepted the latest answer?